# React update a var adding up two states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, var

What I need is to print and save in a variable or in a state the value of globalValue, the sum of the two "numbers".

The proplem with this code is that what is printed in the , is not the real value, but is the penultimate. For example if I put on the Textfields 1 and 1 will show me 0, but if later I change them for a 3 and 3, it will show me 2 because of the 1 plus 1. I can't use a setState inside de "componentDidUpdate" for this reason I'm using a var, but I'm sure there should be a better way.

Thank you for your attention and I hope I can learn wit your answers!

```
var globalValue=0
class ExampleComponent extends Component{
  constructor(){
  super();
   this.state=({
    number1:0,
    number1:0,
   })
}

componentDidUpdate(){
  globalValue=this.state.valu1+this.state.value2,
}

updateNumber1(evt){
  this.setState({
    value1: evt.target.value,
  });  
}

updateNumber2(evt){
  this.setState({
    value2: evt.target.value,
  });  
}

<Textfield value={this.state.number1} onChange={evt => this.updateNumber1(evt)}/>
<Textfield value={this.state.number2} onChange={evt => this.updateNumber2(evt)}/>
<h2>Global value is:{globalValue}</h2>
```

Comment: Why do you even need `globalValue`? Just render the result directly: `<h2>Global value is:{this.state.value1 + this.state.value2}</h2>`

Comment: Besides many inconsistencies (number vs value, commas vs semi-colons, incomplete component syntax, etc...) what is the purpose of storing anything *outside* of react state/props? What are you really trying to do? It's an anti-pattern to store extraneous data that can be simply derived from stored state/props. By updating `globalValue` from `componendDidUpdate` it will ***always*** be a render cycle *behind* the component update that triggered it.

Comment: I need ```globalValue``` because I need to save it in a firebase database, on the other hand I don't need storing it outside, I did it that way because I wanted to use the function ```componentDidUptade```, just because I din't know a better way, if you know some better method please notice me!

Comment: "I need globalValue because I need to save it in a firebase database" - no, you really don't. You can still compute the value when you call the function to update your firebase.

Comment: So it would be better use that?  I mean the adding up directly. ```firebase.database().ref(..).push({globalValue:this.state.numer1+this.state.number2,})```

Comment: Sure, or you could add an explanatory variable within the same scope that the firebase function is called, but there is no need for a global variable or even a state variable to hold the aggregate.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and you patience, I'm just learning and this helps me a lot. This way there is just 1 problem. I was using ```globalValue=globalVlaue.toFixed(2)```, because just I want two decimals. I tried ```<h2> Global value is: {(this.state.number1+this.state.number2).toFixed(2)}</h2>``` but it don't works

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing a lot. A full working demo would be helpful.
But the last 3 lines (I think is the render method) should be a pure function, which only access this.props and this.state as input. Not globalValue. The calculation should be there as well and not in componentDidUpdate. This method is for other side effects.

So just use
`<h2>Global value is:{this.state.number1 + this.state.number2}</h2>`

Comment: The propblem is that I need to safe the ```globalValue``` to a firebase database, so I need the entire value